# How to connect docker container from local host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, dockerfile, docker-machine

Thanks in advance. I have installed docker in windows and calling the container from localhost. I just using port forwarding in virtual box to specify the port. It's working fine. But I need to access entire ports in my local without specification inside the virtual box. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a container, you can bind the "internal" port (the one which is EXPOSEd, 80 for an Apache for example) to the "public" one. You have to specify it in your docker run command or in your docker-compose (PORT
If you can reach each container using the IP (or domain name) and the port (ip.of.the.vm:public_port)

You don't have to bind a port in virtual box.

Comment: can I call that container with any port number?

Comment: Yes if you define it as a public port.